# Print folded code

Tags: pycharm

Is there a way to print folded code?
When I select some folded code, it prints the whole code.
I'd like to print something like:

[image: folded code to print]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, unfortunately. Please vote for the corresponding feature request: [IDEA-172719](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-172719).

Comment: I did vote. Thanks for the link. And the description of the problem in the link is very true. The code above is > 1500 lines long....